# Double Marker Folium

Tags: python, folium, markers

I want to have a custom markers on the map and unique popups for every markered dot.
The code below gives me what I want except for the fact that there are two markers for each dot - my custom and default one. How to leave only mine? Why there are two markers?

```
        fg_other_atms = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Other ATMs", show=False)
        
        geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(atm_other.longitude, atm_other.latitude)
        geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(atm_other[['latitude', 'longitude', 'city_id', 
                                             'region_id', 'trans_cnt','trans_amt']],
                                              geometry=geometry)
        geo_df = geo_df.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
        gjson = folium.GeoJson(geo_df)
        
        for feature in gjson.data['features']:
            folium.Marker(location=list(reversed(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])),
                          icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('Icons/red.png', icon_size=(26, 35))
                           ).add_to(fg_other_atms)
            if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Point':
                    b = folium.GeoJson(feature['geometry'])   
                    popup = '<b>Кол-во операции</b>    ' + str(feature['properties']['trans_cnt'])+ ' '  + '<br><b>Сумма снятий</b>    ' + str(feature['properties']['trans_amt'])
                    b.add_child(folium.Popup(popup))
                    fg_other_atms.add_child(b)
                    
        m.add_child(fg_other_atms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
        fg_other_atms = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Other ATMs", show=False)
        
        geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(atm_other.longitude, atm_other.latitude)
        geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(atm_other[['latitude', 'longitude', 'city_id', 
                                             'region_id', 'trans_cnt','trans_amt']],
                                              geometry=geometry)
        geo_df = geo_df.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
        for row in geo_df.iterrows():
            row_values = row[1]
            location = [row_values['geometry'].y, row_values['geometry'].x]
            popup = '<b>Кол-во операции</b>    ' + str(row_values['trans_cnt'])+ ' '  + '<br><b>Сумма снятий</b>    ' + str(row_values['trans_amt'])
            marker = folium.Marker(location=location,
                                   icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('Icons/red.png', icon_size=(26, 35)),
                                   popup = popup)
            marker.add_to(fg_other_atms)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Анна Демидова, I have have the same problem. Could you please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74572611/folium-how-to-replace-the-default-marker-by-a-custom-one?noredirect=1#comment131676101_74572611