# Folium, How to replace the default marker by a custom one?

Tags: python, folium

I have a folium with the default folium marker and the one I added.
How can I move the folium default marker?

I try this `icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('flights_app/fafa.png', icon_size=(350, 575))`but nothing appears. Any help please

```
icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('flights_app/fafa.png', icon_size=(350, 575))

layer = folium.GeoJson(
    flights_gdf,
    marker=folium.Marker(icon=icon),
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=[
            'flight_number', 'flight_iata', 'dep_iata', 'arr_iata',
            'airline_icao', 'aircraft_icao', 'status'
        ], localize=True),
            ).add_to(m)
```

I just want plane icon

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but check the contents of the custom icon object, does it contain a rather long string of base64? `vars(icon)`

Comment: @r-beginners, thanks. Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Try print(vars(icon)). Also, is the local image path correct? `'./flights_app/fafa.png'`

Comment: @r-beginners, I got this but I don't understand  {'_name': 'CustomIcon', '_id': 'a179112d8329f36cef194bc7b57e983a', '_env': <jinja2.environment.Environment object at 0x7f5bfe986d90>, '_children': OrderedDict(), '_parent': None, 'options': {'iconUrl': 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAVwAAAFcBAMAAAB2OBsfAAAAG1BMVEXu7u7////zUAD/mQD2aQD8gwL+rgf+ywX5yourSAJOAAAPq0lEQVR42uycTW/bSBKGRTg2cqQQwOCrtS79W+3tmf3vstDdznlKvLOAR1dTVaQhxzbVvryxq2i8AlUafebax3cMEFF1xwwQUXXFQgsZr4zy7/AaMEi6+5ruvIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', 'iconSize': (30, 30)}}

Comment: I have checked the content you posted and it is just a white image. Have you tried the method in the previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. May be it's because my image is too small or big?

Comment: Based on the [examples](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSONMarker.ipynb) in the reference, I have created code that conforms to your question, one displaying a local image. (stackoverflow icon) The other example uses a fontawesome airplane. Please take a look at your code and verify with this example where the glitch is. share the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TnKzAAoOX9VzoQsJFCwcw1HN6myQZbeX?usp=sharing) link. I will answer if this is ok.

Comment: I have seen, the two example. The problem is I don't want the default icon. I only want to keep the plane or stars icon in yours examples. My problem is here marker=folium.Marker(icon=icon) with icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('flights_app/fafa.png', icon_size=(350, 575))

Comment: Is the locally available stackoverflow logo not what you are looking for?

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, it's what looking but not for just a single marker but for my whole points using folium.Geojson without iterating by a boucle for.

Comment: Then I think we should simply set the marker in a loop process. The following is a modification of the code I shared in my [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TnKzAAoOX9VzoQsJFCwcw1HN6myQZbeX?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Load the image file using `from PIL import Image` like:

```
icon = Image.open(open('flights_app/fafa.png', 'rb'))
```

And convert it to a `numpy array` in `folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay`:

```
import numpy as np
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(np.array(icon)...
```